# Custom ListView Adapter for Xamarin.Android with MVVMCross

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, adapter, mvvmcross

I need to create a custom `ListView`. I created it and it works, but I need to use `MVVMCross` principles. I put dummy data in the wrong place. I should put it into `ViewModel`, but I'm a little bit confused how to do it.

Well, I have two `.axml` layouts. For the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:elevation="2dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**And for the list item:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/placeIcon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@mipmap/one" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/placeName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:textColor="#1565C0"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Text" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/placeAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:textColor="#DE000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Another Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**So I created the Model:**

```
using System;

namespace My.project.Core.Models
{
    public class SearchResults
    {

        public SearchResults(int Id, int mPlaceIcon, String mPlaceName, String mPlaceAddress)
        {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.mPlaceIcon = mPlaceIcon;
        this.mPlaceName = mPlaceName;
        this.mPlaceAddress = mPlaceAddress;
        }

        public int mPlaceIcon { get; set; }
        public string mPlaceName { get; set; }
        public string mPlaceAddress { get; set; }
        public string mTripCost { get; set; }
   }
 }
```

**And ViewModel:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace My.project.Core.ViewModels
{
    class SearchResultsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

**After that I created the Adapter:**

```
using Android.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using My.project.Core.Models;

namespace My.project.Droid.Views
{
    public class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView txtPlaceName { get; set; }
        public TextView txtPlaceAddress { get; set; }
    }
    public class SearchResultsAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        private Activity activity;
        private List<SearchResults> searchresults;
        public SearchResultsAdapter(Activity activity, List<SearchResults> searchresults)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.searchresults = searchresults;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return searchresults.Count;
            }
        }
        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
             return null;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return searchresults[position].Id;
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var view = convertView ?? activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SearchResultsView, parent, false);
            var txtPlaceName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.placeName);
            var txtPlaceAddress = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.placeAddress);

            txtPlaceName.Text = searchresults[position].mPlaceName;
            txtPlaceAddress.Text = searchresults[position].mPlaceAddress;

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my View. And it's the thing that I did wrong.

```
using Android.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using My.project.Core.Models;

    namespace My.project.Droid.Views
    {
    [Activity]
    class SearchResultsView : BaseView
    {
        protected override int LayoutResource => Resource.Layout.SearchResultsView;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            var lstData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
            List<SearchResults> lstSource = new List<SearchResults>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                SearchResults searchreasults = new SearchResults()
                {
                    Id = i,
                    mPlaceName = "Place " + i,
                    mPlaceAddress = "Address " + i,
                };

            lstSource.Add(searchreasults);
            }

            var adapter = new SearchResultsAdapter(this, lstSource);
            lstData.Adapter = adapter;
        }
    }
 }
```

I need to put this loop inside `ViewModel` but it doesn't work. The links to `Adapter` doesn't work and I can't use it.

How can I fix it? Thanks for your help!